# how to flatten a nested, mixed array of structs in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the following schema in a PySpark dataframe `df`:

```
root
 |-- mydoc: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Driver: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Information: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Car: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Age: long (nullable = true)
```

I would like to flatten the `Information` *array of structs* so that it appears in my PySpark dataframe as

```
flatName     flatId  flatCar         flatAge
"john,mike"  "1,2"   "ferrari,polo"  "12,24"
```

As you can see, I simply want to express each element as a `string` delimited by `,`. I tried various tricks such as

```
df.select(array_join(df.mydoc.Information.Name,','))
```

With no success. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html?highlight=explode#pyspark.sql.functions.explode)

Comment: Hello, thanks! unfortunately I do not want to explode, I want to keep it in the same row...

Comment: Can you share an example of the JSON file (a couple of lines)

Comment: You definitely need to explode because you want one "flatname" per line. So you need at least to explode "mydoc". Then, you'll have a struct and you can simply select : `df.select(F.explode("mydoc").alias("mydoc")).select("mydoc.Driver", "mydoc.information.name") ...`

Comment: ah this is useful. but how can I concatenate all the fields into a string as mentioned? do you mind posting your suggestion as a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of explode, ".*" and groupBy, here's a code:

```
df = df.withColumn("mydoc", explode("mydoc")).select("mydoc.*").withColumn("Information", explode("Information")) \
    .select("Information.*").groupby().agg(
    concat_ws(",", collect_list("Name")).alias("flatName"),
    concat_ws(",", collect_list("Age")).alias("flatAge"),
    concat_ws(",", collect_list("Car")).alias("flatCar"),
    concat_ws(",", collect_list("Id")).alias("flatId")
)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Result:

```
+---------+-------+------------+------+
|flatName |flatAge|flatCar     |flatId|
+---------+-------+------------+------+
|john,mike|12,24  |ferrari,polo|1,2   |
+---------+-------+------------+------+
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want it to be done to all columns, then you can do it with a for loop:

```
df = df.withColumn("mydoc", explode("mydoc")).select("mydoc.*").withColumn("Information", explode("Information")).select("Information.*")
df = df.groupby().agg(*[concat_ws(",", collect_list(col)).alias(f"flat{col}") for col in df.columns])
```

Comment: this is great!! thanks! Just a follow up: how can process multiple columns like this? That is, assume there is a another array `Information2` and I want to flatten its data as as well. (so we end up, in this example as FlatName1, Flatname2, FlatAge1, FlatAge2, etc). How can we do that? In your solution the `select` statement would drop that column... and piping two explode would multiply the rows..

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I updated my answer for multiple columns, for the explode() it can be possibly replaced with selectExpr(), but it will be a little bit of work, I will try to implement it